# Need help in XDP program failing to load with error "R9 offset is outside of the packet"

Tags: filter, packet, ebpf, bpf, xdp-bpf

I have an xdp program that filters packets by quintuple matching. I'm only interested in ip, icmp, tcp, udp headers. I will check each packet's destination ip, source ip, and the protocol field in the ip header to determine the upper layer protocol. If it is icmp, only compare these three pieces of information with the data in bpf_map, and then perform corresponding operations. If it is tcp or udp, you also need to add the source port and destination port. However, when I try to load the XDP program into the kernel in Native mode, it says "R9 offset is outside of the packet". Really don't know why. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Following is the code:

```
xdp.c
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
// #include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include "maps.h"

// struct vlan_hdr {
//  __be16 h_vlan_TCI;
//  __be16 h_vlan_encapsulated_proto;
// };

/* helper functions called from eBPF programs */
// static int (*bpf_trace_printk)(const char *fmt, int fmt_size, ...) =
//          (void *) BPF_FUNC_trace_printk;

/* macro for printing debug info to the tracing pipe, useful just for
   debugging purposes and not recommended to use in production systems.

     use `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe` to read debug info.
 */
// #define printt(fmt, ...)                                                   \
//             ({                                                             \
//                 char ____fmt[] = fmt;                                      \
//                 bpf_trace_printk(____fmt, sizeof(____fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__); \
//             })

SEC("xdp/xdp_ip_filter")
int xdp_ip_filter(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
    void *end = (void *)(unsigned long)ctx->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(unsigned long)ctx->data;
    __u32 ip_src, ip_dst;
    // __u64 offset;
    // __u16 eth_type;

    // struct ethhdr *eth = data;
    // offset = sizeof(struct ethhdr);

    // if (data + offset > end) {
    //     return XDP_ABORTED;
    // }
    // eth_type = eth->h_proto;

    /* handle VLAN tagged packet */
//     if (eth_type == htons(ETH_P_8021Q) || eth_type == htons(ETH_P_8021AD)) {
//  struct vlan_hdr *vlan_hdr;

//  vlan_hdr = (void *)eth + offset;
//  offset += sizeof(*vlan_hdr);
//  if ((void *)eth + offset > end)
//      return 0;
//  eth_type = vlan_hdr->h_vlan_encapsulated_proto; 
//    }

//     /* let's only handle IPv4 addresses */
//     if (eth_type == ntohs(ETH_P_IPV6)) {
//         return XDP_PASS;
//     }

    struct iphdr *iph;
    if (end >= data + sizeof(struct ethhdr)) {
        iph = data + sizeof(struct ethhdr);
    } else {
        return XDP_ABORTED;
    }
    // offset += sizeof(struct iphdr);
    /* make sure the bytes you want to read are within the packet's range before reading them */
    // if (iph + 1 > end) {
    //     return XDP_ABORTED;
    // }
    ip_src = iph->saddr;
    ip_dst = iph->daddr;
    __u8 proto = iph->protocol;

    if (proto == 1 || proto == 6 || proto == 17) {
        __u64 *srcMap_value, *dstMap_value, *protoMap_value, bitmap;
        srcMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&srcMap, &ip_src);
        dstMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&dstMap, &ip_dst);
        protoMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&protoMap, &proto);

        if (srcMap_value == 0) {
            __u32 default_sip = 0;
            srcMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&srcMap, &default_sip);
        }
        if (dstMap_value == 0) {
            __u32 default_dip = 0;
            dstMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&dstMap, &default_dip);
        }
        if (protoMap_value == 0) {
            __u8 default_prot = 0;
            protoMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&protoMap, &default_prot);
        }

        if (proto == 1) {
            bitmap = (*srcMap_value) & (*dstMap_value) & (*protoMap_value);
            __u64 temp = (~bitmap) + 1;
            bitmap = bitmap & temp;
        }
        if (proto == 6) {
            struct tcphdr *tcph;
            if (end >= data + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr)) {
                tcph = data + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr);
            } else {
                return XDP_ABORTED;
            }
            __u64 *sportMap_value, *dportMap_value;
            __u16 sport = tcph->source;
            __u16 dport = tcph->dest;
            sportMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&sportMap, &sport);
            dportMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&dportMap, &dport);

            if (sportMap_value == 0) {
                __u16 default_sport = 0;
                sportMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&sportMap, &default_sport);
            }
            if (dportMap_value == 0) {
                __u16 default_dport = 0;
                dportMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&dportMap, &default_dport);
            }

            bitmap = (*srcMap_value) & (*dstMap_value) & (*protoMap_value) & (*sportMap_value) & (*dportMap_value);
            __u64 temp = (~bitmap) + 1;
            bitmap = bitmap & temp; 
        }
        if (proto == 17) {
            struct udphdr *udph;
            if (end >= data + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr)) {
                udph = data + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr);
            } else {
                return XDP_ABORTED;
            }
            __u64 *sportMap_value, *dportMap_value;
            __u16 sport = udph->source;
            __u16 dport = udph->dest;
            sportMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&sportMap, &sport);
            dportMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&dportMap, &dport);

            if (sportMap_value == 0) {
                __u16 default_sport = 0;
                sportMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&sportMap, &default_sport);
            }
            if (dportMap_value == 0) {
                __u16 default_dport = 0;
                dportMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&dportMap, &default_dport);
            }

            bitmap = (*srcMap_value) & (*dstMap_value) & (*protoMap_value) & (*sportMap_value) & (*dportMap_value);
            __u64 temp = (~bitmap) + 1;
            bitmap = bitmap & temp; 
        }

        __u64 *actionMap_value;
        actionMap_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&actionMap, &bitmap);
        if (actionMap_value) {
            (*actionMap_value) = (*actionMap_value) + 1;
            bpf_map_update_elem(&actionMap, &bitmap, actionMap_value, BPF_EXIST);
            return XDP_DROP;
        }
    }
    return XDP_PASS;
}

char __license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";

maps.h

#define SEC(NAME) __attribute__((section(NAME), used))

static void *(*bpf_map_lookup_elem)(void *map, void *key) = (void *) BPF_FUNC_map_lookup_elem;
static void *(*bpf_map_update_elem)(void *map, void *key, void *value, int flags) = (void *) BPF_FUNC_map_update_elem;

#define BUF_SIZE_MAP_NS 256

typedef struct bpf_map_def {
    unsigned int type;
    unsigned int key_size;
    unsigned int value_size;
    unsigned int max_entries;
    unsigned int map_flags;
    unsigned int pinning;
    char namespace[BUF_SIZE_MAP_NS];
} bpf_map_def;

enum bpf_pin_type {
    PIN_NONE = 0,
    PIN_OBJECT_NS,
    PIN_GLOBAL_NS,
    PIN_CUSTOM_NS,
};

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps/srcMap") srcMap = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
    .key_size = sizeof(__u32),
    .value_size = sizeof(__u64),
    .max_entries = 4194304,
    .pinning = PIN_GLOBAL_NS,
    .namespace = "globals",
};

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps/dstMap") dstMap = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
    .key_size = sizeof(__u32),
    .value_size = sizeof(__u64),
    .max_entries = 4194304,
    .pinning = PIN_GLOBAL_NS,
    .namespace = "globals",
};

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps/protoMap") protoMap = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
    .key_size = sizeof(__u8),
    .value_size = sizeof(__u64),
    .max_entries = 4194304,
    .pinning = PIN_GLOBAL_NS,
    .namespace = "globals",
};

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps/sportMap") sportMap = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
    .key_size = sizeof(__u16),
    .value_size = sizeof(__u64),
    .max_entries = 4194304,
    .pinning = PIN_GLOBAL_NS,
    .namespace = "globals",
};

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps/dportMap") dportMap = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
    .key_size = sizeof(__u16),
    .value_size = sizeof(__u64),
    .max_entries = 4194304,
    .pinning = PIN_GLOBAL_NS,
    .namespace = "globals",
};

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps/actionMap") actionMap = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
    .key_size = sizeof(__u64),
    .value_size = sizeof(__u64),
    .max_entries = 4194304,
    .pinning = PIN_GLOBAL_NS,
    .namespace = "globals",
};
```

Below is the error message：

```
2023/05/18 12:48:21 error while loading "xdp/xdp_ip_filter" (permission denied):
0: (b7) r0 = 0
1: (61) r3 = *(u32 *)(r1 +4)
2: (61) r9 = *(u32 *)(r1 +0)
3: (bf) r1 = r9
4: (07) r1 += 14
5: (2d) if r1 > r3 goto pc+199
 R0_w=inv0 R1_w=pkt(id=0,off=14,r=14,imm=0) R3_w=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R9_w=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=14,imm=0) R10=fp0
6: (61) r1 = *(u32 *)(r9 +26)
invalid access to packet, off=26 size=4, R9(id=0,off=26,r=14)
R9 offset is outside of the packet
processed 7 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0
```

The compilation command I use is `clang -O2 -target bpf -c xdp.c -o xdp.o`.When I use `clang -target bpf -c xdp.c -o xdp.o`,the error message has changed.

```
2023/05/18 12:47:23 map location not supported: map "" is in section ".data" instead of "maps/"
```

I have just entered the field of ebpf in the Linux kernel, and I don't know how to solve the problem. I hope the error can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The bounds check here is not correct. You are checking if you can access up to `struct ethhdr` of bytes, but you should check for `struct ethhdr` + `struct iphdr` since you will be reading from the iphdr next.

```
 struct iphdr *iph;
    if (end >= data + sizeof(struct ethhdr)) {
        iph = data + sizeof(struct ethhdr);
    } else {
        return XDP_ABORTED;
    }
```

A more typical way to do bounds checking is:

```
struct iphdr *iph = data + sizeof(struct ethhdr);
if ((void *) iphdr + sizeof(struct iphdr) >= end)
    return XDP_ABORTED;
```

We first calculate the start of the IP header and make a pointer. (this is save since we are not accessing its fields or dereferencing it). Then we take the start of our header, add its size and check that its less then `end`. After this we know we can access all fields of iph without overrunning bounds.